# Computing volume of a region

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

The problem asks to compute the volume of the region
$$
V = \{(x,y,z): 
0 \leq z \leq x^2 - y^2, \; 
0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}
$$

I am stuck at this ridiculously simple problem. The volume turns out to be $0$, and I am unable to work through the problem the correct way. It reminds me of the problem where the integral of the sine function over the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ turns out to be $0$, which makes no sense at all if we are actually finding the area under the sine curve. I have a feeling the above computation of volume gives us $0$ for the same reason. How do I get around this problem and compute the volume correctly?

Comment: There is a lot of symmetry in this problem, but it's broken by the condition $0 \leq x^2 - y^2$, which is satisfied whenever $|x| \geq |y|$, i.e. for quarter circles on the right and left sides: polar angles $-\frac\pi4 \leq \theta \leq \frac\pi4$ and $\frac{3\pi}4 \leq \theta \leq \frac{5\pi}4$. Convert this integral to polar coordinates!

Comment: What was the integral you ended up computing? It's possible your setup is correct and the only issue you mention needs to be addressed.

Comment: I suggest you draw the different sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is the portion of a cylinder that intersects with the region between the $xy$-plane and the hyperbolic paraboloid $z=x^2-y^2\,.$

- This volume can impossibly be zero.

Due to symmetry we can restrict to $x,y\ge 0$ (see picture) and multiply the result by four.

- Since the paraboloid intersects with the $xy$-plane at the line $x=y$
  we must calculate
  \begin{align}
  V&=4\int_0^1\int_0^x\int_0^{x^2-y^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx=4\int_0^1\int_0^xx^2-y^2\,dy\,dx\\
  &=4\int_0^1x^3-\frac{x^3}{3}\,dx=\frac{2}{3}\,.
  \end{align}
  When instead you miss my second bullet point you might naively calculate
  \begin{align}
  V&=4\int_0^1\int_0^{\color{red}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}}\int_0^{x^2-y^2}\,dz\,dx\,dy
  \end{align}
  which is indeed zero.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution. Thanks also for pointing out where my error was.